# How to store websocket connection?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I am using Websockets for chat implementation in nodejs. I need to send messages to specific connections and how do I do that?

One way I figured by browsing on web was to store the connection with a unique id as key-value pair in an object and then send the data to that specific connection.

I will be scaling this project later on and will have around 3 servers deployed. So storing the websocket connection on server does not seems to be the best way to do it. I tried storing it in MongoDB and accessing it from over there but it didn't work.

So how can I store the connection in the cloud and then access it to send the data? Also can it be done or I am trying it uselessly?

Comment: Maybe you can use socket io with redis adapter. Or https://tsh.io/blog/how-to-scale-websocket/.